# Converting variable names to variables

Tags: r

I'm trying to print out all the variables in my environment that are of a certain type (for example 'matrix). I tried

```
for(f in ls()) {if(is.matrix(f) print(f) }
```

Obviously, this doesn't work because `ls()` returns a list of strings. I tried other things, but I can't seem to convert the string `f` into the variable `f`. Does anyone know how to do that?

In a nutshell, if I have a string variable y that holds "x", and x is also a variable in my environment, I want to use y to access x. Of course, I may not know a priori what value y holds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want `get`, to access the object

```
for(f in ls()) { if(is.matrix(get(f))) print(f) }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `mget()` to get the objects corresponding to a vector of variable names

```
for(f in mget(ls())) { if(is.matrix(f)) print(f) }
```